# Why won't my 2004 dodge durango stay running after jumping it

Tags: electrical, stall, jump-start, voltage

I hooked car reader up and these are the numbers it gave;

- U1120
- P0700
- P0562

Where do I start to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Sorry, we aren't a rescue site. Responses are just from whoever happens to be on at the time. If you still need help with this, please update your question with details of problems before this event, did the jumper cables get crossed at any point, are all fuses intact, etc. If you have already resolved it, please feel free to post an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The codes indicate some trouble in your electrical system.
Did I understand right, it starts and runs as long as the jumper-cables are connected, but does not run on its own?

- Check your alternator - does it provide 13.8 volts?
- Check for broken cables or signs of damage - could be a marten has broken some electrical connections.

Comment: Honest question: what is a [marten](https://detroitzoo.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/marten-tree.jpeg)?